# Instantiate a service without injecting it

Tags: angular

I have a service called titleService that is used by components to set the title of the page in the tab, and on my header. This service as dependencies, so I can't hard inject it.

It works basically like angular native Title service, but with some custom stuff.

Now, I inject this component in my app header component, but my app header is not used when I sign in (outside of private path)

I would like that this service is always instantiated in the app, even when no one use it (cause even if he is not used in the component on sign in, he still set the tab title with a default value)

to resolve that, I import it in my app.module

```
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private _: TitleService
  ) {}
```

but, since I do no use th service, my typescript complain that

> Property '_' is declared but its value is never read.

Is there a way to do fix this other that some hack ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the APP_INITIALIZER. It is an InjectionToken you can use to run some code when your app starts. It is also possible to inject a service here, and execute a function.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    TitleService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (title: TitleService) => () => return title.setDefaultTitle(),
      deps: [TitleService],
      multi: true
    }]
})
```